# Prove that $\lim_{x\to0} f(bx)$ exists, if $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)$ exists

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x)$ be a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lim_{x\to0}\;f(x)$$ exists, and let $b\in\mathbb{R}$. Using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit, prove that $$\lim_{x\to0}\;f(bx)$$ exists.

**A more refined attempt at the solution:**

First, note that $bx\to0$ as $x\to0$ and therefore $ f(bx) \to f(x) $ as $x\to0$.
Thus, 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\;f(bx) = \lim_{x\to0}\;f(x) = L$$ if the limit exists.

Now, we want to prove that $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta'>0$ such that $|x|<\delta' \implies|f(bx)-L|<\epsilon$
Choose an arbitrary positive real $\epsilon$
Since $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ exists, $\exists\delta>0$ such that $|x|<\delta \implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$
Hence $\exists\delta>0$ such that $|bx|<\delta \implies|f(bx)-L|<\epsilon$
and,  $\exists\delta>0$ such that $|x|<\frac{\delta}{|b|} \implies|f(bx)-L|<\epsilon$
So if we set $\delta' = \frac{\delta}{|b|}$, we obtain,
$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta'>0$ such that $|x|<\delta' \implies|f(bx)-L|<\epsilon$ (q.e.d)

Comment: maybe you should post your attempt of solution first. Anyway, note that if $x\rightarrow 0$, then also $bx\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @user23116 I added an attempt at the solution

Comment: I think you're assuming $f$ is continous, that could not be true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the clean way to do it if you're using $\varepsilon - \delta$ arguments anyway.

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. We want to bound the quantity $|f(bx) - L|$. We know that for some $\delta'$ if $|x| < \delta'$, then $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ by definition. It follows then that if $|bx| < \delta'$, that $|f(bx) - L| < \varepsilon$.

What bound on $|x|$ is required (this can be in terms of $\delta'$)? You now have your $\delta$.

Comment: Hi, I made a more refined attempt based on your suggestion. Would be great if you could take a quick look. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's almost perfect! I think you accidentally wrote $|x| < \delta$ in your last line where you meant $\delta'$, however.

Comment: Made the appropriate changes. Thanks for the help!