# Prove $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists $\implies\lim_{x\to 0} f(x^2)$ exists

Tags: limits, proof-verification

Want to show $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists $\implies \lim_{x\to 0} f(x^2)$ exists.  (I recently posted a similar variation of the question, where I asked if it was true for $a$ rather than $0$ which can be found here: [Prove that $\lim_{x\to0} f(bx)$ exists, if $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)$ exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037329/prove-that-lim-x-to0-fbx-exists-if-lim-x-to0-fx-exists))  Anyway, here is my attempted proof:

Assume $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=l$.  Then $\forall\epsilon_0 \exists\delta_0 \forall x:0<|x|<\delta_0 \implies |f(x)-l|<\epsilon_0$

It follows that $\forall\epsilon_0 \exists\delta_0 \forall x:0<|x^2|<\delta_0 \implies |f(x^2)-l|<\epsilon_0$ (this is the part I was most questionable about - am I allowed to do this?).

Now let $g(x)=x^2$, and it can be shown that $\lim_{x\to 0} x^2 = 0$.  Hence $\forall\epsilon_1 \exists\delta_1 \forall x:0<|x|<\delta_1 \implies |x^2|<\epsilon_1$.  Then let $e_1 = \delta_0.$ And hence from the statement in the last line, there exists a $\delta_1$ for which $|x^2|<\epsilon_1 = \delta_0$

Then for a given $\epsilon$ I take my $\delta = \delta_1$.  Then it follows that $\forall x:0<|x|<\delta \implies |f(x^2)-l|<\epsilon$

Comment: " (this is the part I was most questionable about - am I allowed to do this?)."  Yes.   If $|u-0|=|u| < \delta_0$ then $|f(u) - l|< \epsilon_0$.  So if $|x^2|< 0$ then $x^2 \in \{u: |u| < \delta_0\}$ so $|x^2| < \delta_0$ *will* imply $|f(x^2) - l| < \epsilon_0$.  But you've got to prove that there is a $\delta_1$ so that $|x|< \delta_1 \implies |x^2|< \delta_0$.... which you did in the next paragraph.  So .... yes, that is just fine.

Comment: ... oh... I,, personally don't like the "it can be shown that $\lim_{x\to 0} x^2 = 0$.  I'd like a bit of a recap as to why that is.... but maybe I'm being picky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (this is the part I was most questionable about - am I allowed to do this?).

You are.  But if it makes you uncomfortable skip it and work back.

$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = L$ is given. so: For any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ so that $0<|x| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

And $\lim_{x\to 0}x^2 = 0$ because for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta=\sqrt \epsilon> 0$ so that $0<|x|<\delta\implies |x^2| < \delta^2 =\epsilon$.

So for any $\epsilon$ let $\delta_{inbetween}$ be a value so that $0< |x|<\delta_{inbetween} \implies |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ and let $\delta$ be a value so that $0<|x|<\delta \implies |x^2| < \delta_{inbetween}$.

Then $0< |x|< \delta \implies 0< |x^2| < \delta_{inbetween} \implies |f(x^2)-L| < \epsilon$.

So $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x^2) = L$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to observe that as $x\to0\implies x^2\to 0$.

Note that the same property holds also for $x\to1$.

More in general it is true that

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \quad \text{exists}\implies \lim_{x\to a} f(g(x)) \quad \text{exists}$$

for any $g(x)$ such that $g(x)\to a$ with $g(x)\neq a$.

We are excluding the cases for which $f(a)\neq\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ or $f(a)$ is undefined and $g(x)=a$.

Comment: Can I use statements like $x \rightarrow \implies x^2\rightarrow 0$ in rigorous arguments?  I understand that it means 'as $x$ approaches 0, $x^2$ approaches 0' but is there a clear way to show this implication?  I've seen it often in proofs I've read but have no idea how to incorporate them myself since I don't really understand what it is saying.

Comment: @SaranWrap We need to use definition of limit to be rigorous.

Comment: Can I see how the $x \rightarrow 0 \implies x^2 \rightarrow 0$ argument looks like rigorously?

Comment: We need to show that $$\forall \epsilon>0 \quad \exists \delta >0 \quad \forall x\neq 0 \quad |x|<\delta \quad |x^2|<\epsilon$$ then it suffices to assume $\delta \le \sqrt{\epsilon}$.